PHImageManager requestImage is nil with limited access with fastFormat
I have iPhone 15 Pro Max.
private func fetchAssetsForHeader() -> [PHAsset] {
    let fetchLastOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchLastOptions.fetchLimit = MediaPickerRootConstants.maxItemsCount
    fetchLastOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    fetchLastOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(mediaType = %d AND duration < \(MediaPickerRootConstants.maxVideoLength)) || (mediaType = %d)", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue, PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
    return PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchLastOptions).toArray
}

private let imageRequestOptions: PHImageRequestOptions = {
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.version = .current
    options.resizeMode = .fast
    options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
//    options.isSynchronous = true
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    return options
}()

PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: viewModel.asset,
    targetSize: MediaPickerRootConstants.mediaItemSize,
    contentMode: .aspectFill,
    options: self.imageRequestOptions)

The problem that if PHAuthorizationStatus is .limited and PHImageRequestOptions is .fastFormat, that requestImage return nil with error:
Optional([AnyHashable("PHImageErrorKey"): Error Domain=PHPhotosErrorDomain Code=3303 "(null)", AnyHashable("PHImageResultIsDegradedKey"): 0, AnyHashable("PHImageResultRequestIDKey"): 1])

If I change PHAuthorizationStatus to .authorized or remove .fastFormat deliveryMode, image fetch successfully. What can be an issue with that?
